# String vs string in java language?

Tags: java, string

What is the difference between usage of **String** and **string**(mind capital "S" and small "s") in **Java** syntax?
Please let me know the differences as many as you know!

Comment: One is a class, and one is just a (key)word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, **String** is a class name (its full name is java.lang.String). As the java.lang package is imported automatically, you can use String class as follows:

```
String myString = "this is my string!";
```

There's no reserved **string** word in Java, but you can create a variable with that name:

```
String string = "this is a string!";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String string = "string";
```

`String` is a type - [java.lang.String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and `string` is just a name of variable. This is the main difference which leads us to where each can be used.

Take a look on documentation:

- [Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)
- [Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)
- [What Is an Object?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html)

Answer (score 0):

String is a class in Java. It is used by almost everyone, to store a bunch of characters. string is a type of 'data type'. Most people would generally use str or string for a variable name of the type  of class String
For example: "abc" is a type of string, but an 'object' of the String class.